# Twilio Reject listener not called on client, disconnect called instead

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

TL;DR: The "reject" event listener in Twilio javascript client is not being called after callee rejected, but "disconnect" event listener is. I want to know when the outbound call has been rejected by the other peer, and can't find how.

I'm using Twilio in order to make browser-to-browser calls (based on this repository: https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/browser-calls-node).

Caller client is using device.connect to initiate the call.
I receive a hook to my server (route defined in Twilio apps console).
My server then respond to Twilio with a twiml string that includes a dial command, looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
   <Dial answerOnBridge="true" action="/calls/webhooks/status" record="record-from-answer">
      <Client>
         600b3a66ebc8f8ba51d7aed6
         <Parameter name="sessionId" value="53d70205-6723-4402-afe5-68169c2bd018" />
      </Client>
   </Dial>
   <Record />
</Response>
```

The client string is a registered agents.
When the callee has received the incoming call, the UI displays a popup with an answer and decline button.
When the user hit decline, I'm using `call.reject()` to reject the incoming call.
Then Twilio hitting a status webhook I define, and if the body includes a `DialCallStatus` equal to `busy`, I'm responding with Twiml string which command for reject, looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Reject/></Response>
```

Now here's the problem:
The caller "reject" event listener isn't fired, and also not the "cancel".
The caller "disconnect" event listener is indeed being called - But It's also called when each of the party hangs up.
When the callee is answer the call everything works fine, and the connection "accept" event listener is being fired.

It make it impossible to differentiate between these 2 states - is the call been answered and hanged up, or does the call been rejected by the agent.

I've tried everything - connect the event listener to the call, to the device, and I have no idea why it's not being called.

My code on the caller side look like this:

```
   const device = new Twilio.Device(token, {
       codecPreferences: ["opus", "pcmu"],
       fakeLocalDTMF: true,
       enableRingingState: true,
    });

  device.on('disconnect', () => {
    // this is actually being called after the Reject response from the server... but I want the reject listener to be called instead.
  })
  const call = device?.connect({ sessionId: state.sessionId });
 

  state.call.on('reject', (call) => {
     // this is not being called... :(
  });
  state.call.on('canceled', (call) => {
     // this is not being called either
  });
```

Am I doing something wrong with my code?
And if the reject event listener is never being fired and only the disconnect one is, how can I know why the disconnection happened?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

From [the documentation on the `reject` event](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/connection#reject-handler):

> #### `.on('reject', handler())`
>
> Register a handler function to be called when the connection is rejected and `Connection.status()` has transitioned to closed. This is raised when `Connection.reject()` is called.

The `reject` event is only called when your `Connection` object rejects an incoming call. Not when an outbound call is rejected.

If you want to tell the difference between a call that was answered by the other end or not you should listen for the events `ringing`, and `accept`. If the call only goes through the `ringing` and `disconnect` events, then it was hung up on. If it is accepted then disconnected, then a connection was made.

You could also see what happened to the call in the `action` webhook. The [`DialCallStatus` will tell you whether the call was completed, no-answer, busy, etc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#dialcallstatus).

Comment: @ASpirin This answer was for the version 1 SDK. I recommend you write a new question and fully explain what's going on. Please be more specific than "not working" and share your code.